# How to install Maven artifact with sources from command line?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

How to install Maven artifact with sources?

so later I don't need to open a project in eclipse to see some code.

**EDIT:**
I do know I can add to pom.xml this code

```
<plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
                <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                                <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                </execution>
        </executions>
</plugin>
```

but I would like to do it from command line(to make it more universal).

Comment: And where do you want those sources?

Answer (score 181, accepted):

To download sources for your dependencies:

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse -DdownloadSources=true
```

To attach sources to an installation:

```
mvn source:jar install
```

It's also preferable to use the goal `source:jar-no-fork` in your pom as described on the [maven-source-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/usage.html) page.

Comment: but the sources of installed snapshot do not exists :(

Answer (score 68):

Simple, get your sources and JavaDocs:

```
mvn dependency:resolve -Dclassifier=javadoc
mvn dependency:resolve -Dclassifier=sources
```

Comment: @csgeek Question is ambiguously worded, can interpret various ways. Cmd downloads mvn src and doc and installs locally so no manual mapping is needed from Eclipse. See dogbane's answer for installing src for a locally built jar.

Comment: much better and cleaner option.. better than individually tampering pom.xml or eclipse settings, those things change more often.

Comment: "mvn source:jar install" wouldn't change the pom or any Eclipse settings.... it's the Maven goal to install the sources of a local code repo in the .m2 repository. (F.ex. if you git cloned some snapshot version that you want to refer to from another project.) The dependency resolution is meant for downloading external source or javadoc jars.

Answer (score 4):

Please use `mvn source:jar` install to install the Maven artifacts.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. It only generates a sources jar. I want to combine with `mvn clean install` that way  both object and source jars are in my m2. I'm accessing them from Android Studio using gradle.

Answer (score -2):

It is quite easy with eclipse, right click the project in project explorer view, click maven menu item , then click download sources..

Comment: but the sources of installed snapshot do not exists :( I get error 24.02.11 10:23:23 CET: Can't download java-source for artifact my:project:1.2.18-SNAPSHOT

Comment: Well, you have clarified your question.. My answer is not valid anymore.

Comment: why? maven is about doing things automatically. I cant access it because the jar with it was not created.