# Maven download source codes command line using POM.xml

Tags: maven-2

I want to download the source codes of `json-simple` library using maven2 command line interaface. So, I download this .pom file into ~/project/pom.xml

http://json-simple.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pom.xml

And then, using the relevant SO question's answer: [How to install Maven artifact with sources from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102571/how-to-install-maven-artifact-with-sources-from-command-line), I try to download source codes with the following commands,

```
$ cd ~/project
$ mvn eclipse:eclipse -DdownloadSources=true
$ ls
```

The output is only the `pom.xml`. What is wrong?

```
$ mvn --version
```

Apache Maven 2.2.1 (rdebian-8)

Answer (score 5):

Use the [get](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html) goal of the [dependency](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/index.html) plugin

Full command line (execute somewhere - you do not need a pom)

```
mvn -DgroupId=com.googlecode.json-simple 
  -DartifactId=json-simple 
  -Dversion=1.1.1 
  -Dclassifier=sources 
  -DremoteRepositories=http://nexus.dmz1.heuboe.hbintern:8080/nexus/content/repositories/central/ 
  org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:get
```

or as a oneliner

```
mvn -DgroupId=com.googlecode.json-simple -DartifactId=json-simple -Dversion=1.1.1 -Dclassifier=sources -DremoteRepositories=http://nexus.dmz1.heuboe.hbintern:8080/nexus/content/repositories/central/ org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:get
```

Normally I am using Maven 3 but I tested this also with Maven 2.2.1 on Windows and it works.

You can also consider to use the [m2e](http://eclipse.org/m2e/) Maven Integration in eclipse (check the eclipse Marketplace to install this if not already installed) instead of the maven-eclipse-plugin (eclipse:eclipse). You than have an eclipse preferences option to download the sources.

Comment: Build failure. You must specify at least one goal or lifecycle phase to perform build steps.

Comment: @celebisait Possibly not copied correct to one line. Take the oneliner I added.

Comment: I am still having problems. I get the following output when I used your one line command: `Scanning for projects... Building Maven Default Project task-segment: [org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:get] (aggregator-style) [dependency:get {execution: default-cli}] Resolving com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:jar:sources:1.1.1 with transitive dependencies BUILD SUCCESSFUL`. However, I cannot find the source codes. Nothing is getting downloading.

Comment: @celebisait You will find the sources inside the downloaded jar artifact at `.../.m2/repository/com/googlecode/json-simple/json-simple/1.1.1/json-simple-1.1.1-sources.jar`

Comment: _Why doesn't it work with `-Dartifact` parameter instead of those three?_ __Edit:__ my mistake, I didn't read the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html) well and left out the `classifier` from the `artifact` parameter string.

Comment: Is there also a way to *not* manually specify `groupId` etc., but have Maven read that from the given `pom.xml`?